# Multiple Screens support - emulators

Tags: android, user-interface, android-emulator

I'm developing an Android app and I would like to support multiple screens.

I checked the dashboard in the link below and there are 10 types of screen configuration in use:
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens

I got the dimension of the screens from the link below: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

and then I created the following emulators to test my app on:

- large_ldpi_2.3_800x480_120
- large_mdpi_2.3_800x480_160
- large_xhdpi_2.3_800x480_320
- normal_hdpi_2.3_800x480_240
- normal_ldpi_2.3_400x240_120
- normal_mpdi_2.3_480x320_160
- normal_xhdpi_2.3_960x640_320
- small_hdpi_2.3_640x480_240
- small_ldpi_2.3_320x240_120
- xlarge_mdpi_2.3_1280x800_160

format:

```
<size>_<density>_<android version>_<size>_<density>
```

Am I doing this right? 
What is the best practice?

Comment: Yes, you already have good references and a diligent set-up.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is no need to be worry about the emulator size when you test your app. And there are three folders for placing your different images for different resolutions when your app runs on a device and app chose the best resolution image for the device when you run it on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

There are specific Android API calls that can, at runtime tell you what density and (small/large/normal) screen size a handset has. However, as a developer we should not need to worry about individual handsets at all. All we need to do is to have ldpi/mdpi/hdpi assets and small/normal/large layouts in the apk. Android internally handles everything.

Dont forget to get an indepth understanding of how Android determines which assets to use and aliasing [like this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html).

The definitions are:

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp.

large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp.

normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp.

small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp. (Android does not currently support screens smaller than this.)

Here are some more examples of how this works with real screens:

A QVGA screen is 320x240 ldpi. Converting to mdpi (a 4/3 scaling factor) gives us 426dp x 320dp; this matches the minimum size above for the small screen bucket.

The Xoom is a typical 10” tablet with a 1280x800 mdpi screen. This places it into the xlarge screen bucket.

The Dell Streak is a 800x480 mdpi screen. This places it into the bottom of the large size bucket.

A typical 7” tablet has a 1024x600 mdpi screen. This also counts as a large screen.

Comment: I created the ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi images and the small/normal/large/xlarge layouts.

It didn't work for these device configurations (the images were not aligned correctly):
- 4.65in 720p (Galaxy Nexus);
- 4.7in WXGA;
- 7in WSVGA (Tablet);
- 7in WXGA (Nexus 7);

Do you know what I am missing?